# For a Maven 3 plugin what is the latest way to resolve a artifact

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

What is the latest way of resolving an Artifact within a Maven 3.2.5 plugin.   ArtifactResolver and ArtifactFactory(depreciated) are in the compat library which implies that there is a newer/better way of resolution,  but I can not find any examples, docs or searches that do not use the above.

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a blog from sonatype on exactly this:

http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/how-to-use-aether-in-maven-plugins

This is the code from the blog entry (full details are obviously described there):

```java
public MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * The entry point to Aether, i.e. the component doing all the work.
     */
    @Component
    private RepositorySystem repoSystem;

    /**
     * The current repository/network configuration of Maven.
     */
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${repositorySystemSession}", readonly = true)
    private RepositorySystemSession repoSession;

    /**
     * The project's remote repositories to use for the resolution of plugins and their dependencies.
     */
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.remotePluginRepositories}", readonly = true)
    private List<RemoteRepository> remoteRepos;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        ArtifactRequest request = new ArtifactRequest();
        request.setArtifact(new DefaultArtifact( "org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.0" ) );
        request.setRepositories( remoteRepos );

        ArtifactResult result = repoSystem.resolveArtifact( repoSession, request );
    }
```

}

You can then use `result.getArtifact()` to get the artifact and `result.getArtifact().getFile()` to get the file of the artifact if you need it.

Comment: Please use annotations and not xdoclet anymore: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html

Comment: I have been using this example code at 3.0.5 and it works perfectly.   If I run using 3.2.5 I get all sorts of class issues,  one of which is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.sonatype.aether.artifact.Artifact

I did read somewhere, not sure where,  that maven is running with eclipse aether instead of sonatype aether.   Not sure what impact this has on my dependencies and imports.

Comment: Ok,  found the answer, use the the org.eclipse.aether dependencies:-
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
   <artifactId>aether-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
   <artifactId>aether-util</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
  </dependency>

But this means the plugin won't run below 3.2.?   which is fine.

Comment: Therefore, @DB5 answered the question,   but modified to use the org.eclipse.aether libraries.   Ta